# Convert Expo project to Original React Native project

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, expo

I did `yarn run eject` to eject but it gave me this warning

```
Warning! We found at least one file where your project imports the Expo SDK
```

I know I have some modules which use Expo API like this -

```
await Expo.Font.loadAsync({
      Roboto: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf'),
      Roboto_medium: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf'),
    });
```

Now I want to convert this to React Native Components so that I can eject without any errors so that I get
`index.android.js` & `index.ios.js` in the root folder like we do while using `react-native init example`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After 4 hours, I got the answer..

Had to install `exp` using `npm i -g expo` & then used `expo eject` to detach the project
Also I added some fields in `app.json` for it to work as follows

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Project",
    "slug": "project",
    "sdkVersion": "18.0.0",
    "privacy": "public",
    "android": {
      "package": "com.example.project"
    }
 }
}
```

Docs are given [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v15.0.0/guides/detach.html)

SideNote: It doesn't create the folder structure like when done using `react-native init`... It creates `android` & `ios` folders respectively.

Comment: Is this solution still working? The link does not working anymore.

Comment: @EatenTaik have no idea