# How to convert expo project to simple react native

Tags: react-native, expo

I am working in expo project and recently i want to convert my whole expo project to simple react native project. is there any proper solution or command for this.thanks.

Comment: use this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44748213/convert-expo-project-to-original-react-native-project

Comment: you need to eject right?

Answer (score 0):

There is documention about it and it answers important question like "Should i eject to ExpoKit?". Use this [link](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/eject/) and this [link](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v35.0.0/workflow/customizing/) for getting information.