# How to convert expo app to react native cli? without re-coding it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How to convert expo app to react native cli? without re-coding it? I have a old expo app which I want to run but when i am running it with new react native version its showing too much errors now it has many deprecated functions is their any way to convert that app to react native cli? or any way to run that project without expo go? because expo go dont support SDK version 37

Comment: There is a way to do so but it is irreversible one. That is `eject-your-project`

Comment: @Sudarshan explain me how to do that i am using android with windows 10 i just want that project run

Comment: You can refer this 
https://pagepro.co/blog/how-to-eject-from-expo-managed-workflow-to-bare/

But, you should make yourself familiar with `bare-workflow` and `managed-workflow`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can convert your expo project to a react-native-cli project using expo eject.
You should check out @deadcoder0904's answer to this question: [Convert Expo project to Original React Native project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44748213/convert-expo-project-to-original-react-native-project)

But, I'd definitely make a backup of your project before trying such things. Because this is a one way fix and we should be maintaining a older version in case of disaster.